# Google Drive SDK

Tags: google-drive-api

I am developing an app in C++ which will run in a Windows desktop environment  This will be distributed to a number of customers and I need to store log files from the customers in a central location where I can access them. Is Google drive a suitable platform for this and if so what is the best approach?  Should I be looking at an Application Owned Account for example?  Also I am concerned by the paragraph in the Google documentation:

"Note that there are limits on the number of refresh tokens that will be issued; one limit per client/user combination, and another per user across all clients. You should save refresh tokens in long-term storage and continue to use them as long as they remain valid. If your application requests too many refresh tokens, it may run into these limits, in which case older refresh tokens will stop working"

How long does a token remain valid for and what are the limits on refresh tokens?

Best regards

Trevor

Answer (score 0):

You could use google drive for this, its not a bad idea really.  But since its only log files you are storing and they are all owned by the application your not going to be needing to bother with user Oauth2.  You could do it with a google drive service account.   This way the application owns the account and they are just uploading data to it.

https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts

Comment: with service account you can't buy more space and I has a limited  space.

Comment: I would suggest Google Cloud Storage as all the files are log files

Comment: Give it permission to a folder on your drive account